# Need help understanding AUTOINCREMENT from SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm learning SQLite from this webiste: [SQLite Tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/).

I was reading the article they had on the [AUTOINCREMENT](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/) command.

My question had to do with their explanation of *why* this feature is useful:

> The main purpose of using AUTOINCREMENT attribute is…
>
> > To prevent SQLite to reuse value that has not been used or from the previously deleted row.

I'm confused about this explanation as it doesn't explain in detail what the implications of this statement is.

Could someone please give more detail about what happens in the background, if this feature is implemented differently for different platforms or specific packaging of the engine in different packages (npm packages etc.).

Also, more importantly, give examples of use cases where using this feature would be necessary and what would be both the proper and improper ways of using it.

Thanks to all!

Comment: I'm pretty sure they meant "to prevent SQLite from reusing a value that *has* already been used", not the negative. Considering the people that have written the site haven't even bothered to add their names to it or any other information I would take the content with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To prevent SQLite to reuse value that has not been used or from the
>   previously deleted row.

`AUTOINCREMENT` property ensure that newly generated id will be unique that will be not from any already used id in that column or should not be from id that has been deleted. It is mostly used in primary key of table where we need unique property which has not been used so far.

In most of relational database, there is `AutoIncrement` property but in Oracle, I've seen `Sequence` which similarly acts AutoIncrement property.

For e.g : if you have 10 rows which has `AutoIncrement` column called id and has value from 1 to 10. Now, you delete all rows and insert new one, then new row will have id = 11 becase 1 to 10 has already been used. You do not need to specify id value as it automatically fills up new row id value by checking previous inserted value.

Comment: The sequence seems to be more powerful. You can create one on its own and request to get the next X numbers for batch processing so you can ensure that the elements which were inserted together have numbers without gaps. Which doesn't seem to be possible with autoincrement if more than one process is writing to the table.

Comment: @maraca : you are right. From my experience, I didn't find any autoincrement property in Oracle so I just want to let OP know about the usage of sequence as autoincrement,

Comment: Yes, it's a good answer, I just meant to say that although the sequence is a little harder to use it has its benefits (but usually just one of the concepts is available, so no choice).

Comment: There is no TRUNCATE in SQLite.

Comment: @downvoter : please care to comment so that I can improve my answer !!!

Answer (score 1):

This feature is usually being used on the table's primary key (I personally prefer to name it ID), like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

If you are learning SQLite, you should know that the table's primary key absolutely mush be unique for each record in this table. 
So if you are inserting a record to the table without AUTOINCREMENT on its primary key, the database will force you to specify ID of each new record.

If there are already some records in your table, you may ask yourself a question like "What ID whould I put in the record to ensure that it will be unique?"

This is what AUTOINCREMENT was created for. If AUTOINCREMENT is set on the table's primary key, you don't longer need to specify it when inserting a record, so you don't longer need to think what ID to put there.

Now how does it work. If AUTOINCREMENT is set on the table's primary key, a special number of added records (let's name it as a variable "added") is being stored along with the table's data in the database. When you issue the INSERT command with this table, its ID will be calculated like

```
added + 1
```

And the added variable will be incremented (autoINCREMENT)

Initially, added's value is 0.

For example, as Akash KC already said, if 10 records were added to the table, the next record's ID will be 11.

The detail is that AUTOINCREMENT doesn't mind deletions - if you take an empty table, add 10 records to it, delete one of them with ID 5 (for example) and then add a new one, its ID will be 11 as well.

Comment: *So if you are inserting a record to the table without AUTOINCREMENT on its primary key, the database will force you to specify ID of each new record.* Not true. `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is enough to make SQLite to auto generate values for primary key. [Documentation](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html): On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. **This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used.**

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. So my answer is completely wrong? You possibly should make yours

Comment: A specific ID is just given once to a record. Auto-increment ensures that if a record was inserted after another it has a higher ID. However there can be gaps due to deletion or rollbacks.